# Is it possible to update a cached file from the android device w/o removing the app?

Tags: android, caching, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I found out that the only way to run my updated preferences.xml file on the app was to remove the app from the device before running it again.

Before that I tried:

- rebuilding
- cleaning
- File->Invalidate cache / restart
- delete ~/.gradle/cache/
- delete project/.gradle
- restarting my machine

and it would still run the old version.

Is it possible to automate this? Or at least make android studio un-cache the files that were edited?

Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "run my updated preferences.xml file on the app" means.

Comment: I changed a key in  ListPreference, and when I would print the keyset I would still get the old value of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just Clear data in the app setting page.

Yes you can automate it by running:

```
adb shell pm clear my.wonderful.app.package
```

There is also an [IDEA plugin](https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea) that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your `preferences.xml` is a definition of a `PreferenceScreen`, including your mentioned `ListPreference`. This is completely independent of the `SharedPreferences` that holds the results of the user settings values on the `PreferenceScreen` itself. Just because you change `preferences.xml`, you do not immediately affect any existing `SharedPreferences`. This is no different than changing the name of an `<input>` element on a Web page and somehow expecting that your MySQL database on the Web server will magically change.

If you change the key of a `ListPreference`, the next time the user goes into the `PreferenceScreen`, the `ListPreference` value will not be set. In other words, the behavior will be as if the user had never visited that preference before.

In addition, any value under the old key that the user supplied will remain in your `SharedPreferences` indefinitely. That may not be a big problem.

If you want to *migrate* existing values from the old key to the new one, you have to handle that yourself. This would be akin to implementing `onUpgrade()` in a `SQLiteOpenHelper` to modify your database schema to change a column name in a table. Android itself does not come with a `SharedPreferencesHelper` that assists you the way `SQLiteOpenHelper` does, though there may be third-party libraries that offer this.

Comment: I have this line on my `onCreate()` method in the MainActivity.java:

     `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);`

so I assumed that it would use these every time it's running, or does it only initialize the default values when it's installed the first time? And does running the app not reinstall it?

Comment: @LLL: "does it only initialize the default values when it's installed the first time?" -- I suspect that may be the case, from my reading of [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java). "And does running the app not reinstall it?" -- running the app upgrades the app to the new edition, but it leaves all existing data intact, including any existing `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: So short of uninstalling the app every time I update that file, there's nothing I can do?

Comment: @LLL: Personally, I never use `setDefaultValues()`. For development, you can uninstall/reinstall the app, or clear the data through Settings, or clear the data via `adb pm clear` as indicated in another answer to your question. However, once you ship your app, you need to think about your *users* and how these changes affect them, not just yourself.

Comment: Well to be honest, I'm just learning Android right now and rewriting the code from [Android 6 for programmers](http://www.allitebooks.com/android-6-for-programmers-3rd-edition/) book. And it was like that there.This cached file took like 3 hours to solve because I made a typo the first time I made it. What would you advise to use instead of default values? Also if I moved the line from onCreate() to onStart() would it be ran everytime the app starts instead of only when it is installed?

Comment: @LLL: "What would you advise to use instead of default values?" -- you can already specify a default value on the getters (e.g., `getString()`), so I just use that. "Also if I moved the line from onCreate() to onStart() would it be ran everytime the app starts instead of only when it is installed?" -- it already is run every time. However, AFAICT, `setDefaultValues()` only does its work the first time you run it. After that, it thinks that the default values are already set (because they are).

Comment: So the app knows that it's been ran before?

Comment: @LLL: Yes. If you look at [the source for `PreferenceManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java), there is a magic preference value indicating that the defaults were already set. Now, you may be tempted to clear that, to trick `setDefaultValues()` into running again. However, I suspect that this will overwrite any values already set by the user, which will not make the user happy.

Comment: @LLL: The only way that I know if that you could ensure that the `SharedPreferences` has what you want is if you code it yourself. **You** know what the old key was. **You** know what the new key is. **You** can see if the new key has a value, in which case you leave it alone. If it does not, **you** can see if the old key has a value, and if it does, save it under the new key. And if that is missing too, **you** can write some default value under the new key.